# Threading in tensorflow's input pipeline

Tags: multithreading, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

**Background**

Typical input pipeline in tensorflow looks like follows:

```
                  tf.train.string_input_producer(list_of_filenames)
                         (creates queue of filenames)
                                   |
                                  \|/
           fixed length reader reads records from the files
                                   |
                                  \|/
    Read records are decoded and processed(eg if dealing with images then cropping,flipping etc)
                                   |
                                  \|/
            tf.train.shuffle_batch(tensors,num_threads)
        (creates a shuffling queue and returns batches of tensors)
```

**Problem**

Q1) There is no argument of num_threads in the function tf.train.string_input_producer().Does it mean that only single thread is dedicated to reading the filenames from filename queue?

Q2) What is the scope of num_threads argument of the function tf.train.shuffle_batch() i.e. do the number of threads mentioned here are used to read,decode and process files as well or they are just used to create batches of tensors?

Q3) Is there a way to print which thread read the filenames or records from a particular file i.e. sort of a record of work done by each thread?

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions at once on SO. Asking multiple questions in one, well, question does not work with the Q/A format SO is using and can turn away people that can only answer one of the questions.

Comment: @etarion they may look multiple questions but they are highly correlated.They are all parts of input pipeline of tensorflow.If anyone capable of answering any one of them would definitely be able to answer all with little effort.I just wanted to be sure about the answers.

Comment: "If anyone capable of answering any one of them would definitely be able to answer all with little effort." Anyone qualified to make that statement would be able to answer the questions, so if you can make that statement, why don't you answer your question yourself?

Comment: I knew this was going to be raised and that is why I said "I just wanted to be sure about answers."Since these questions are nowhere answered clearly in tensorflow documentation,I have tried finding them with some test cases.I do have rough answers to all the above questions.Still I wanted some fresh eyes to make sure I was going correct.If the bounty expires and I receive no answers,I would be happy to share my answers!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your data loading operations are performed within the tensorflow graph, what you'll want to do is launch one or more threads to iterate over the reader/enqueue operations. Tensorflow provides a QueueRunner class that does exactly that. The Coordinator class allows you to manage the threads pretty trivially.

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues

This is the example code from the link above:

```
# Create a queue runner that will run 4 threads in parallel to enqueue
# examples.
qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue, [enqueue_op] * 4)

# Launch the graph.
sess = tf.Session()
# Create a coordinator, launch the queue runner threads.
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
enqueue_threads = qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, start=True)
# Run the training loop, controlling termination with the coordinator.
for step in xrange(1000000):
    if coord.should_stop():
        break
    sess.run(train_op)
# When done, ask the threads to stop.
coord.request_stop()
# And wait for them to actually do it.
coord.join(enqueue_threads)
```

If you were loading/preprocessing samples outside of the graph (in your own code, not using TF operations), then you wouldn't use QueueRunner, instead you would use your own class to enqueue data using a `sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict={...})` command in a loop.

Q1: Number of threads is handled with: `qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, start=True)`

Q2: TF sessions are thread safe, each call to `tf.run(...)` sees a consistent snapshot of the current variables as of when it begin. Your QueueRunner enqueue ops can run any number of threads. They'll queue up in a thread-safe manner.

Q3: I haven't used `tf.train.string_input_producer` myself, but I think you'd have to request a tensor later in the graph that `dequeued` the data, just add that tensor to your list of requests in `sess.run([train_op, dequeue_op])`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!I would just like to clear some aspects of second question.Say the enqueue op above follows some reading and preprocessing of data through some in-house tensorflow functions(say fixed length reader and cropping,flipping before enqueuing).The 4 threads that run in parallel above,would they be responsible just for enqueuing the data or for reading+preprocessing+enqueuing?

Comment: You will pass an op to the QueueRunner, the QueueRunner will just run that op in a loop, nothing more (other than housekeeping). So you should just request the QueueRunner to do an op that handles all the reading, preprocessing, and enqueuing. Your enqueue op will presumably depend on your preprocessing, which will presumably depend on your reading - so it should just be a matter of enqueueing and letting TF figure out the appropriate dependencies.